# Vim disable mouse only in insert mode

Tags: vim, autocmd

When I insert mode sometimes my cursor moved because my palm accidentally placed on trackpad. So, I want to make autocmd to disable mouse on insert mode and enable it in normal mode.

I write it like this:

```
  autocmd InsertEnter * set mouse=""
  autocmd InsertLeave * set mouse=a
```

It worked to disable the mouse. But, when I leave the insert mode, the mouse not activated.

How to make this work?

Edit: I just found out that `InsertLeave` not triggered when I'm using `CTRL_C`. Unfortunately, I always use `CTRL_C` to exit insert mode. Is there any workaround for this?

Edit 2: I found out `UserGettingBored` event too. But it seems this event is just a joke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
set mouse=n
```

to only enable mouse in normal mode

Comment: I ended up using `set mount=nv` because sometimes I select text with the mouse, but otherwise this is a perfect answer. Thanks!